# DFA Reporting API - get data directly from API

Tags: api, google-api, double-click

I've been looking and searching for quite a while on https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/reporting/v1.3/. What I'm trying to find is a way to directly get the data via the API. Is this possible?

As far as I can see you can create reports, run this report which generates a file and then get the download url to the file with the actual data in it. Is it not possible to directly get the data through the DFA reporting API?

Answer (score 1):

No! I don't think it is. As far as I know the API is more like a programmatic recreation of the web interface. It doesn't operate like I'd expect an API to work.